# How to build an AngularJS app with Yesod

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, haskell, yesod

I managed to successfully write a small app using Yesod. Now I am in the phase in which I want to add better interaction to it, and I would like to do this using AngularJS.

As far as I can see, the support for AngularJS in Yesod is still experimental. Moreover, the documentation I found so far is quite unaccessible for me. I don't master all of the Yesod concepts.

So I was wondering, what are possible ways to integrate AngularJS and the Yesod framework. What I'm thinking about doing is:

1. Writing the front-end in AngularJS.
2. Develop the web-service using Yesod.
3. Connect the front-end and the web-service by means of GET and POST http requests. Information can be sent to the server by means of input forms (leveraging some of Yesod capabilities in this way), and information can be sent to the front-end by means of JSON objects.

Ideally I'd like to write everything in Haskell, but in the current state of affairs that may not be a possibility. Thus I wanted to ask if the alternative I have in mind is a good one, and whether there are ways to improving it.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see Michael Snoyman's repository: https://github.com/snoyberg/yesod-js ?

Comment: Yes. That's one of the "inaccessible to me" resources I referred to. I need something in a tutorial format given my limited understanding of Yesod. I wouldn't want to end up with a solution I don't understand. That's why I though about taking the "shortcut" I described.

Comment: See this: http://blog.wuzzeb.org/posts/2015-02-04-yesod-angular-bower.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So I don't know a thing about haskell or yesod but it wasn't too difficult to integrate angular with Yesod. **Please do follow the steps in order to end up with a working app!**

**Here are the steps I followed to set up**

- Followed the Yesod quickstart to set up a Yesod app

  **brew install haskell-stack**

  **stack new my-project yesod-sqlite && cd my-project**

  **stack install yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc**

  **stack build**

  **stack exec -- yesod devel**

> Now you can access a simple OTB web app [here](http://localhost:3000/). The generated app has the following structure:

[image]

- I used bower to set pull in angular, jQuery and bootstrap
- I used a custom .bowerrc file to pull the packages inside the static folder

**.bowerrc**

```
{
    "directory": "static/bower_modules"
}
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": [
      "Atef Haque <atefth@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "description": "Haskell with Angular",
  "keywords": [
      "haskell",
      "angular"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
      "**/.*",
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components",
      "static/bower_modules",
      "test",
      "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
      "angular": "~1.5.3",
      "angular-route": "~1.5.3",
      "bootstrap": "~3.3.6"
  }
}
```

> Running bower install installs the packages inside the *static/bower_packages* directory

[image]

- Now I added my scripts and templates inside static/scripts and static/templates directories respectively

[image]

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.title = 'home';
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'static/templates/layout.html',
        controller  : 'HomeCtrl'
    });
}])

app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'Comment', function ($scope, Comment) {
    $scope.comments = [];
    $scope.post = function () {
        Comment
        .post($scope.message)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.comments.push(data);
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
}])

app.service('Comment', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.post = function (comment) {
        return $http
        .post('http://localhost:3000/comments', {message: comment})
    }
}])
```

**layout.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header" align="center">
          <h1>Haskell <small>+</small> Angular</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="well well-lg">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form role="form" ng-submit="post()">
                        <legend>Post a comment</legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Message</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" ng-model="message">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="border: 2px solid steelblue">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Comment #{{ comment.id }}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            {{ comment.message }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> At this point we're all set up on the front-end. Now I had to configure the backend to serve just the one index.html from where angular can take over!

- I edited the templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet and got rid of most of the default stuff

**default-layout-wrapper.hamlet** *head*

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>{{ title }}
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <style link="rel" src="static/bower_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    ^{pageHead pc}
```

**default-layout-wrapper.hamlet** *body*

```
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
      <div ng-view>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/bower_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/bower_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/bower_modules/angular/angular.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/bower_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/scripts/app.js">
```

*Unfortunately Stackoverflow probably doesn't allow hamlet code snippets so I hade to separate it*

> Now when you go [here](http://localhost:3000/) you'll have a web app with an angular front-end powered by a yesod backend.

---

**Things that might seem like magic**

1. Posting comments works without any backend code? Nope, it comes OTB :)

Hope I could make thinks clearer than they were!

Comment: Also, if you want angular routing to function properly you will need to make a catch all route in `config/routes` that serves this `default-layout-wrapper.hamlet`. Like the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31011940/7941330

Comment: there's this post too: http://blog.wuzzeb.org/posts/2015-02-04-yesod-angular-bower.html

Comment: Now that I read the post, I think I certainly understand a bit more than when I answered the question!